# Como obtener una respuesta SSH en formato Json o en un Array

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssh, redes, router

Buen día comunidad, estoy estancado con este problema.
Tengo un método que me ejecuta una conexión SSH a un Router(RAIDUS) y al mismo tiempo ejecuta una linea de código especifica.

El método es el siguiente:

```
$connection =ssh2_connect('IP A CONECTAR',22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection,'admin','admin');

$stream=ssh2_exec($connection,'/ip address print where interface=<sstp-indicadorusuario>');
stream_set_blocking($stream,true);
$stream_out =ssh2_fetch_stream($stream,SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
return stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

Esta es la respuesta que obtengo:

```
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic # ADDRESS NETWORK INTERFACE 0 D "Direccion ip numero1" "Direccion ip numero2"
```

El dilema es, de la cadena anterior lo único que necesito almacenar es la "direccion ip numero2"
No encuentro la forma de cambiar el formato de respuesta SSH para por lo menos convertirla en un array o un json y asi extraer solo ese dato, alguna idea? existe alguna librería dentro de codeigniter 3 para resolver este dilema? o dentro del propio PHP?.
De ante mano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Usando una expresion regular y la funcion [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) puedes lograr extraer la informacion que necesitas:

```
$stream_out =ssh2_fetch_stream($stream,SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$contents=stream_get_contents($stream_out);
$output=[];
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/',$contents,$output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
return $output;
```

$output contendra un arreglo 2xN de entradas guardadas, siendo

`$output[0][0]` la primera expresion encontrada (ej: `"direccion ip numero2"`), y `$output[0][1]` la primera expresion extraida entre parentesis (ej: `direccion ip numero2`)